# Multiple output extensions in assemble

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, assemble

I have a grunt file like this (part of the assemble config):

```
pages: {
    files: [{expand: true,
      cwd: 'src/pages/',
      src: '**/*.hbs',
      dest: 'dist/',
      ext: '.html'
    }]
  }
```

This way it takes every hbs file and renderes them with html extension. Is it possible to have a css file in the same folder as the .hbs file, and that assemble moves it to the same folder as the compiled html file.

To explain some more, i want every file other than .hbs files to just be moved to the same location as the compiled hbs file. Is this possible with Assemble?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with another Grunt plugin, the [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) and this task:

```
copy: {
  main: {
    files: [ 
      {expand: true, cwd: 'src/pages/', src: ['**', '!**/*.hbs'], dest: 'dist/', filter: 'isFile'}
    ]
  }
},
```

This way it copies every file other than hbs files to the same folders as assemble generates the html-files.